# Is there a way to make a persistent button without view in discord.py?

Tags: discord.py

I create buttons manually like that:

```
class But(Button):
    def __init__(self,label,style,id):
        super().__init__(label=label,style=style, custom_id=id)
    
    async def callback(self,interaction):
        pass
```

Because I want to set all parameters like label,style and id when creating a button. But https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/views/persistent.py example here shows only way to make persistent views. Is there a way to make buttons, not nested into the view persist?

I tried to make persistent view and add buttons to it, but then only buttons nested in this view persist:

```
async def setup_hook(self) -> None:
        self.add_view(persist())
```

```
class persist(View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(timeout=None)

    @discord.ui.button(label="Test persistence", style=discord.ButtonStyle.red,custom_id="persistent_view")
    async def callback(self,interaction,button):
        await interaction.response.send_message("Persists!")
```

```
view = persist()
button1 = But(label=label,style=style, id='1')#I get style and label in slash command
view.add_item(button1)
await interaction.response.send_message("text",view=view)
```

Answer (score 2):

The only other way, which I employ myself, is to use the  on_interaction event.

As the name implies, the event fires whenever an interaction is triggered.

However, even then, you will need a way to recognize the interaction so as to react in the appropriate manner to it, which might be difficult with an entirely dynamic id

Answer (score 0):

In command function:

```
@app_commands.command(name= "test", description="test command")
async def test(self, interaction):

     button = Button(label=label, style=style)
     async def button_callback(interaction):
         await interaction.response.edit_message("Hello!")
 
     button.callback = button_callback

     view = View()
     view.add_item(button)
     await interaction.response.send_message(content="Hi", view = view)
```

or

```
async def create_button(btn_label, btn_stlye):
      button = Button(label=btn_label, style=btn_stlye)
      async def button_callback(interaction):
          await interaction.response.edit_message("Hello!")
 
      button.callback = button_callback

      view = View()
      view.add_item(button)
      return view
```