# How do I make dynamic buttons permanent?

Tags: discord.py

I created a cog with a command that adds 1 to 5 buttons based on the input provided. Everything works correctly until I turn off the bot; when I restart it, the command fails.

```
import os
import json
import discord
from discord import app_commands
from discord.ext import commands
import logging

class AddRolesCog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot: commands.Bot):
        self.bot = bot
        self.data_folder = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'data')  
        self.file_path = os.path.join(self.data_folder, 'persistent_role.json')  

        if not os.path.exists(self.file_path):
            with open(self.file_path, 'w') as f:
                json.dump({}, f)

    async def setup_hook(self) -> None:
        # For dynamic items, we must register the classes instead of the views.
        self.add_dynamic_items(Self_Roles.button_callback)


    def load_persistent_roles(self):
        # Lê o arquivo persistent_role.json e armazena as informações em self.persistent_roles
        with open(self.file_path, 'r') as f:
            self.persistent_roles = json.load(f)

    @app_commands.command(name=app_commands.locale_str('add_roles', category='Moderation'), description='Create action roles.')
    @app_commands.default_permissions(mute_members=True)
    async def _roles(
        self, 
        interaction: discord.Interaction,
        channel: discord.TextChannel,
        role_1: discord.Role, 
        role_2: discord.Role = None, 
        role_3: discord.Role = None, 
        role_4: discord.Role = None, 
        role_5: discord.Role = None,
    ):
        try: 
            list_roles = [role for role in [role_1, role_2, role_3, role_4, role_5] if role is not None]
            await interaction.response.send_message(f'Painel de cargos criado com sucesso em {channel.mention}', ephemeral=True)
            
            eRole = discord.Embed(
                title="Pegue seu cargo!",
                description="Clique nos botões abaixo para adicionar ou remover os cargos desejados.",
                color=discord.Color.random()
            )

            # Atualiza o JSON com as informações dos cargos
            self.load_persistent_roles()
            for role in list_roles:
                self.persistent_roles[str(role.id)] = role.name

            with open(self.file_path, 'w') as f:
                json.dump(self.persistent_roles, f)

            # Cria os botões na instância da classe Self_Roles
            view = Self_Roles(list_roles, self.file_path)
            await channel.send(embed=eRole, view=view)

        except Exception as e:
            logging.error({e})
    
    # Lê o arquivo persistent_role.json durante o setup hook
    # load_persistent_roles()

class Self_Roles(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self, roles, file_path):
        super().__init__(timeout=None)
        self.roles = roles
        self.file_path = file_path

        try:
            for role in self.roles:
                button = discord.ui.Button(label=role.name, style=discord.ButtonStyle.primary, custom_id=str(role.id))
                button.callback = self.button_callback
                self.add_item(button)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f'Erro no for: {e}')

    async def button_callback(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        try:
            role_id = int(interaction.data['custom_id'])
            role_name = discord.utils.get(self.roles, id=role_id)

            if role_name:
                if role_name in interaction.user.roles:
                    await interaction.user.remove_roles(role_name)
                    await interaction.response.send_message(f"O cargo '{role_name.name}' foi removido!", ephemeral=True)
                else:
                    await interaction.user.add_roles(role_name)
                    await interaction.response.send_message(f"O cargo '{role_name.name}' foi adicionado!", ephemeral=True)

                # Atualiza as informações do cargo no arquivo persistent_role.json
                with open(self.file_path, 'r') as f:
                    data = json.load(f)

                data[str(role_id)] = role_name.name

                with open(self.file_path, 'w') as f:
                    json.dump(data, f)

                print(data)

        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(f'Erro no callback: {e}')


async def setup(bot: commands.Bot):
    await bot.add_cog(AddRolesCog(bot))
```

I tried to base myself on the example code from discord.py, but as I didn't understand what is happening, I also failed to apply it to my needs.

Additionally, I created a JSON file to try to pull information from it, but that also didn't work. What would be the correct way to have permanent buttons?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to make a persistent button without view in discord.py?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74877423/is-there-a-way-to-make-a-persistent-button-without-view-in-discord-py)

Comment: Unfortunately, no, as it is precisely in the recognition of the interaction that my biggest problem lies here! Still, thank you very much for the response!